# how to join data nodes in firebase using angularfire2 v5.0 and display them together

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire5

I am making an *ionic 3* app and integrating it with firebase. I couldn't get proper docs on **retrieving** data.

1) What is the best way to use firebase is **firebase SDK** or **angularfire2 v5.0** (I am creating a simple app).

2) How to retrieve all student's data and their respective classes.
**like this** => **suhaib khan** of **B.tech** section **B**

this is my database structure:

[image]